# does Oracle support EVENTDATA() function?

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for the equivalent function EVENTDATA() which is supported in MS SQL SERVER in ORACLE. any suggestion ?

Comment: So what does this function do? What is the _actual_ underlying problem you are trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent. Oracle does however allow you to work with system events which is likely to allow you to achieve the same effect. The doc section, including the available options for each type of trigger is at https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-triggers.htm#LNPLS794. Some examples are at https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/system_events.html